# Facing a problem while Handle an input with React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I try to handle the user's text input with hooks.

```
 const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({
firstName:"",
lastName:"",
email:"",
telNum:"",
contactType:"Tel.",
message:"",
agree:false
```

});

and I try to update the values by

```
  const handleChange = event => {
setInputValues({ ...inputValues, [event.target.name]: event.target.value,});
}
```

and the event:

```
onChange={handleChange}
```

Sample input Field code:

```
    <FormGroup row>
          <Label htmlFor='firstname' md={2}>
            First Name
          </Label>
          <Col md={10}>
            <Input
              type='text'
              id='firstname'
              name='firstname'
              placeholder='First Name'
              value={firstName}
              valid={errors.firstName === ""}
              invalid={errors.firstName !== ""}
              onBlur={handleBlur("firstName")}
              onChange={handleChange}             />
            <FormFeedback>{errors.firstName}</FormFeedback>
          </Col>
        </FormGroup>
```

But whenever I typed something in the input field. I Can't find the value that I entered un the input field.
I didn't understand what happened here. Please Help me to get out from this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo error in your code. name property is firstName not firstname.

```
<FormGroup row>
          <Label htmlFor='firstname' md={2}>
            First Name
          </Label>
          <Col md={10}>
            <Input
              type='text'
              id='firstname'
              name='firstName'
              placeholder='First Name'
              value={inputValues.firstName}
              valid={errors.firstName === ""}
              invalid={errors.firstName !== ""}
              onBlur={handleBlur("firstName")}
              onChange={handleChange}             />
            <FormFeedback>{errors.firstName}</FormFeedback>
          </Col>
        </FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `value` to `value={inputValues. firstName}`